C return libcurl response from example as parameter
I'm following the code from this libcurl example and everything seems to work perfectly as a standalone, so i wanted to make it a function in its own file to reuse in other code.
I added two parameters, one char *addr for the web address and another char *response to retrieve the response from curl, so the template became
extern int curlGet(char *addr, char *response);

and i return the resulting response with a
memcpy(response,chunk.memory,chunk.size+1);

and then i call it on my main file with the following code
int main(void){
    char *tmp=malloc(1);
    curlGet("www.google.com",tmp);
    printf("%s\n",tmp);
    //free(tmp);
    return 0;
};

The addr parameter works without a problem, but the tmp one constantly throws a segmentation fault (core dumped), and if i uncomment the free(tmp) i get a
free(): invalid next size (fast)
Aborted (core dumped)

my instincts tell me its something with memory allocation, but i'm too new to c to know why.
**Edit from comments
This is the modifications i made to the example to try to return the answer:
if(res!=CURLE_OK){
    fprintf(stderr, "curl_easy_perform() failed: %s\n",
        curl_easy_strerror(res));
    return -1;
}
curl_easy_cleanup(curl_handle);
memcpy(response,chunk.memory,chunk.size+1);
free(chunk.string);
return 0;


You allocated space to hold 1 character (so an empty string). A segfault is to be expected...

i first tried with a straight char *tmp; but then it would crash without doing anything, with the malloc(1) the printf actually returns the response, but still throws the segfault. wouldn't the memcopy be in charge of resizing it correctly?

memcpy() doesn't resize anything.

ok how should it be then? i'm sorry if its a really stupid thing to ask, i'm new to c and to be honest i'm just trying stuff to see what sticks to the wall here, i still don't fully grasp the memory handling and pointers stuff

"I added two parameters," to what? Did you rename the main function from the example? If yes, then how is your pointer related to the chunk variable used in the example?

"first tried with a straight char *tmp;" Your compiler should have told you that you used an uninitialized variable. Reading all your warnings, you should have never reached that crash because you should not even try to run your code while you get severe warnings during compilation.

@Shawn i'm asking here because reading the book isn't helping me to understand what's happening here. i know that to you this must seem like really easy stuff, but its not for me, and telling me to keep banging my head against a book that i'm not understanding isn't helping. what's the correct way to do this then?

@Gerhardh yes, i renamed it as getCurl and i just passed it as a char *response parameter from which i hoped to get the text back, replacing the printf with a memcopy, like i put on the question. the compiler told me that char *tmp was wrong, so i tried doing what the example does in the WriteMemoryCallback to return the str, but clearly that was enough

That example allocates memory and stores pointer in chunk.memory. This is reallocated in the callback. How did you try to get that memory back to main? You are hiding the important parts from us. Also, you cannot assign a new value to a parameter that is defined as char *tmp. This value will not be visible outside the called function as C passes all arguments by value, i.e. by making a copy. Your tmp variable will will be uninitialized after returning from curlGet, no matter what you do inside that function.

@Gerhard i didnt know that passing a char *tmp wouldn't work, as i said i just replaced the printf from the example with a memcopy(response,CHUNK.memory,CHUNK.size+1) and it returned the string, and then segfaulted. i'll add the returning part to the question

Please stop posting useless random snippets from your code. The example you linked does not contain chunk.string. You also did not show the signature of the changed function. Without that, we can only guess what you are doing. We need to see all changes. That is why we prefer a MCVE. The only thing we can say for sure is, that the pointer is still uninitialized when you copy to it. You must pass the address of your pointer to your function and assign the content of chunk.memory to it in your function. Assuming you did not modify the handling in your callback.

From the fragments you provided I think, this is what you are looking for:
Modification to the linked example:
void curlGet(const char *URL, char **Buffer)
{
  CURL *curl_handle;
  CURLcode res;
 
  struct MemoryStruct chunk;
...
  /* get it! */
  res = curl_easy_perform(curl_handle);
 
  /* check for errors */
  if(res != CURLE_OK) {
    fprintf(stderr, "curl_easy_perform() failed: %s\n",
            curl_easy_strerror(res));
  }
  else {
    /*
     * Now, our chunk.memory points to a memory block that is chunk.size
     * bytes big and contains the remote file.
     *
     * Do something nice with it!
     */

    *Buffer = chunk.memory;     // <<< Assign the buffer to the address you provided.
 
    printf("%lu bytes retrieved\n", (unsigned long)chunk.size);
  }
 
  /* cleanup curl stuff */
  curl_easy_cleanup(curl_handle);
 
//   free(chunk.memory);   // <<< DO NOT FREE THIS MEMORY. WE STILL USE IT!
 
  /* we are done with libcurl, so clean it up */
  curl_global_cleanup();
}

int main(void)
{
    char *tmp = NULL;
    curlGet("www.google.com", &tmp);  // Pass the address of your pointer.

    printf("%s\n",tmp);

    free(tmp);  // Now you must free it here instead of in curlGet.
    return 0;
};

You do not reserve any memory inside your curlGet function. You simply use memcpy to dump all the content to your reserved buffer that can only take 1 byte. This results in undefined behaviour which causes a segfault in your case.
You must provide more memory. And this is already done in the callback of the linked example. You just need to provide it to the caller.
In C all parameters are passed by value. That means if you pass tmp to curlGet, then the function only gets a copy. You cannot change it inside your function as the change would not be visible at the caller.
Therefore you must pass &tmp instead.

Thanks, that worked perfectly and actually explained some doubts i had, specially the bit about functions passing parameters by value, i did not know that. i'm sorry if my question seemed dumb, i'm new to C and the concept of pointers and address is a little new to me. thank you
